# Proving a basic property about derived sets and unions

Tags: general-topology

I'm having some trouble showing these two equal each other. I was doing some research and apparently this is not always true in a topological sense but I think that's out of the scope of this class.

$(A \cup B)' = A' \cup B'$

$A'$ is the set of all derived points of A.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

The easier containment is $A' \cup B' \subset (A \cup B)'$.

For the harder containment, suppose $x \in (A \cup B)'$.  We need to show if $x \notin A'$ then $x \in B'$.  Since $x \notin A'$ there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $A \cap U \subset \{x\}$.  Let $V$ be any open set containing $x$ and consider that

1)  $U \cap V$ is an open set containing $x$

2) $x \in (A \cup B)'$

and you should discover that $x \in B'$.