# Topology over $\mathbb N$.

Tags: general-topology

I want to solve this exercise:

> Let $U\subset \mathbb N$ such that if $n\in U$ and $m \mid n$, then
>   also $m\in U$. Prove that the family of this sets form a topology over
>   $\mathbb N$. Find a base for this topology. Find the interior,
>   derived, closure, boundary, exterior and the set of isolated points of
>   $A=\{1,3,4\}$ and $B=\{2\}$.

So $U$ is the set of the divisors of $n$ (let's call it $U_n$) and I suppose that 'the family of this sets' means $\left\{ U_n \right\} _{n\in\mathbb N}$. I visualize it like $\tau\colon=\left\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,5\},\dots\right\}$.

I know that a topology over $X$ is a subset $\tau \subset \mathcal P (X)$ satisfying the following axioms:

1. $\varnothing,X\subset \tau$
2. The arbitrary union of elements in $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$.
3. The finite intersection of elements in $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$.

But in this case,

- We don't have $\varnothing\subset \tau$ (unless we assume that $0\in \mathbb N$ and $\varnothing = U_0$).
- We don't have $\mathbb N \subset \tau$. Or do we? Is it safe to assume that there is a number $N$ that it is a multiple of every natural number? (So $U_N=\mathbb N$).

I don't know if I am defining the topology in a wrong way.

Comment: Such sets are not necessarily the set of divisors of some $n$; for example, the set of all powers of $2$ will be open.

Comment: You need $\emptyset \in \tau$ and $X \in \tau$. Since $\tau$ is a subcollection of $P(X)$, $X \subset \tau$ would mean that $X$ is a family of sets, which it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the family of those sets $T$. Let us show that $T_0 = T \cup \{ \emptyset \}$ is a topology.

First, $\emptyset \notin T$, so we have to adjoint it to $T$ "by hand". Done.

Next, $\Bbb N \in T_0$, obviously: for every $n \in \Bbb N$, the divisors of $n$ are still in $\Bbb N$.

Let $U,V \in T_0$. If any of them is $\emptyset$, then $U \cap V = \emptyset \in T_0$. If $U,V \ne \emptyset$, then let $n \in U \cap V$. Let $m$ be a divisor of $n$. Then $m \in U$ and $m \in V$ because $U,V \in T$, so $m \in U \cap V$, therefore $U \cap V \in T$.

Let $\{U_i \mid i \in I \} \subseteq T_0$. If $U_i = \emptyset \ \forall i \in I$, then $\bigcup _{i \in I} U_i = \emptyset \in T_0$. If at least one $U_i$ is non-empty, then let $n \in \bigcup _{i \in I} U_i$. There must exist a $j \in I$, then, such that $n \in U_j$. In particular, this means that $U_j \ne \emptyset$, so $U_j \in T$. Let $m$ be a divisor of $n$. Since $U_j \in T$, then $m \in U_j$, so that $m \in \bigcup _{i \in I} U_i$, which shows that $\bigcup _{i \in I} U_i \in T \subset T_0$.

---

Let now $U_n = \{ m \in \Bbb N \mid m \mid n \}$ be the set of the natural divisors of $n$ . Notice that each $n \in \Bbb N$ belongs to $U_n$, so $(U_n)_{n \ge 0}$ covers $\Bbb N$. Next, think of $U_m \cap U_n$. You would like a $U_d$ such that $U_d \subseteq U_m \cap U_n$. Choose $d = \gcd (m, n)$; if $k \in U_d$, then $k \mid d$, and since $d \mid m$, then $k \mid m$ so $k \in U_m$. Similarly, $k \in U_n$, so $k \in U_m \cap U_n$, therefore $U_d \subseteq U_m \cap U_n$. [It follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Definition_and_basic_properties) then that $(U_n)_{n \ge 0}$ is a base for $T_0$.

---

Let us now look at $B = \{ 2 \}$. The only posibilities for $\mathring B$ are $\emptyset$ and $B$. If $B$ were an open set, then all the natural divisors of $2$ should belong to it; but $1 \notin B$, so $B \notin T$, leaving as the only possibility $\mathring B = \emptyset$.

The closure of $B$ is extremely interesting and weird. Remember that $\bar B$ is made of *all the limits of sequences from $B$*. Fortunately, since $B$ contains a single point, there is a single sequence living in $B$, namely the constant sequence $2, 2, 2, \dots$. Unlike what you expect, the limit of this sequence is not just $2$! Consider an even number $2n$. Pick any open subset containing it; this open subset will then contain all the divisors of $2n$, so in particular it will contain $2$. Any neighbourhood of $2n$ contains the terms of the sequence! This shows that every even number is a limit point for it, which in particular shows that this topology is not Hausdorff. It follows that $\bar B = \{0, 2, 4, 6, \dots\} = \{ 2n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$.

It immediately follows that $\partial B = \bar B \setminus \mathring B = \{ 2n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$.

Now, remember that $B'$ is the set of limits of *non-constant* sequences from $B$. Since the only sequence from $B$ is constant, it follows that $B' = \emptyset$.

It follows immediately that the set of isolated points is $\bar B \setminus B' = \{ 2n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$.

The exterior of $B$ is, by definition, $\Bbb N \setminus \bar B$ (the odd numbers).

The conclusions hold almost verbatim for every subset made of a single natural number.

---

Let us finally study $A$. Remember that the interior of a set is *the largest open set contained in it*. The subsets of $A$ are $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{3,4\}, \{1,3,4\}$. Of these, the subsets containing $4$ do not also contain $2$ (which divides $4$), so they cannot belong to the topology. Of the remaining ones, the largest one is abviously $\{1,3\}$, so $\mathring A = \{1,3\}$.

The closure is easier: just remember that the closure commutes with finite unions, so

$$\overline {\{1,3,4\}} = \overline {\{1\}} \cup \overline {\{3\}} \cup \overline {\{3\}} = \{ 1 \cdot n \mid n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{ 3 \cdot  n \mid n \in \Bbb N \} \cup \{ 4 \cdot n \mid n \in \Bbb N \} = \\
\Bbb N \cup 3 \Bbb N \cup 4 \Bbb N = \Bbb N ,$$

where for each set made of a single number I have applied the result obtained previously for $B$.

It immediately follows that $\partial A = \bar A \setminus \mathring A = \Bbb N \setminus \{1,3\}$.

The derived set, too, [commutes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498904/derived-sets-prove-a-cup-b-a-cup-b) with [finite unions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692166/proving-a-basic-property-about-derived-sets-and-unions), so $A' = \{1\}' \cup \{3\}' \cup \{4\}' = \emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset = \emptyset$, where again I have used the result obtained for $B$.

The isolated points are $\bar A \setminus A' = \Bbb N$.

The exterior is just $\Bbb N \setminus \bar A = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 5):

**First,** the axiom is that $\varnothing \in \tau$ and $X\in\tau$, not that $\varnothing\subset \tau$ and $X\subset \tau$.

**Second,** you seem to assume that every $U$ must be the set of divisors of a particular $n$. That's not what the definition says -- it just says that *if* you find some $n$ in $U$, then all its divisors are in $U$ too.

For example, $\{1, 3, 5, 9\}$ is a valid $U$ because it contains all the divisors of $1$ (that is, just $1$ itself) and all the divisors of $3$ ($1$ and $3$), and all the divisor of $5$ ($1$ and $5$), and all the divisors of $9$ ($1$ and $3$ and $9$).

$\varnothing$ is a perfectly good $U$ by this definition -- it has no members, so the condition is vacuously satisfied: All the divisors of the members it doesn't have are in $\varnothing$ too.

$\mathbb N$ itself is a perfectly good $U$ too: For every $n$ you can name, all its divisors are elements of $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answer by Henning Makholm, the definition doesn't say that sets of divisors are all open sets, just that they form [base of topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)). Thus, to show that this is indeed topology, you could show that sets of divisors form a base:

**(1)** they obviously cover $\mathbb N$ since for any $n\in\mathbb N$, $n\in U_n =\{ m\in \mathbb N\,:\, m\mid n\}$,

**(2)** $k\in U_m\cap U_n \iff k|m$ and $k|n \iff k|\gcd(m,n) \iff k\in U_{\gcd(m,n)}$.